# Motion blur image not working in diagonal direction

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to simulate  motion blur kernel as in Gonzalez book.My code below works perfectly well for horizontal and vertical direction but doesn't work in diagonal direction.
Does anyone know where is the problem?

```
% Degrade the image to produce motion blurred images
% shown in Figures 5.26 of text book
clear; clc; 
f=imread('cover.jpg');
[M N] = size(f);
%[u,v]=freqspace([M N]);
%[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
T=1;a=0.1;b=0.1;r=(-1)^.5;
%center=ceil(N/2);
for u=1:M
   for v=1:N
      s=(pi*(a*u+b*v));
      H(u,v)=(T/s)*sin(s)*exp(-r*s);
   end
end
F=(fft2(f));
%Degrading the original image by multiplying H by F in frequency domain.
G=F.*H;
g=abs(ifft2(G));
%Displaying results
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(mat2gray(f)); title('f: Original'); 
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(mat2gray(g));title('Degraded Image by motion');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Vertical Motion
for u=1:M
      for v=1:N

      H1(u,v)=(T/(pi*(a*u)))*sin(pi*(a*u))*exp(-r*pi*(a*u));

      end
end
%Degrading the original image by multiplying H by F in frequency domain.
G1=F.*H1;
g1=abs(ifft2(G1));
%Displaying results
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(g1,[]); title('Vertical Motion'); 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Horizontal Motion
for u=1:M
      for v=1:N

      H2(u,v)=(T/(pi*(b*v)))*sin(pi*(b*v))*exp(-r*pi*(b*v));

      end
end
%Degrading the original image by multiplying H by F in frequency domain.
G2=F.*H2;
g2=abs(ifft2(G2));
%Displaying results
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(g2,[]); title('Horizontal Motion');
```

[image]

Correct output :
[image]

Comment: why do you say it does not work?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Because the result is incorrect for diagonal part,

Comment: How is it correct? how does it look like?

Comment: It should be like Fig5.26 Gonzalez book @AnderBiguri

Comment: Please, add al relevant information in the post itself. Otherwise only people who has teh book can understand and help you.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry you are right,i edited the post.

Comment: In your code which one is the diagonal? "degraded by image motion" ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes.